# get sub string in between mix symbols

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get sub string my output should look like gmail,outlook,Skype.
my string values are

- 'abc@gmail.com'
- 'cde.nitish@yahoo.com'
- 'xyz.vijay@sarvang.com.com'

  somthing like this as you can see its having variable length with mix symbol '.' and '@'
  string values store in table form as a column name Mail_ID and Table name is tbl_Data

i am using sql server 2012

i use chart index for getting sub string

```
select SUBSTRING(Mail_ID, CHARINDEX('@',MAil_ID)+1, (CHARINDEX('.',MAil_ID) - (CHARINDEX('@', Mail_ID)+1))) 
from tbl_data
```

And i want my output like:

```
'gmail'
'yahoo'
'sarvang'
```

Please help me i am newbies in sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a temp table with your data and write below query its worked

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
DATA NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #T
VALUES('abc@gmail.com'),
('cde.nitish@yahoo.com'),
('xyz.vijay@sarvang.com.com')


SELECT *,LEFT(RIGHT(DATA,LEN(DATA)-CHARINDEX('@',DATA,1)),CHARINDEX('.',RIGHT(DATA,LEN(DATA)-CHARINDEX('@',DATA,1)),1)-1)
FROM #t
```

AND its a output of my T-SQL

```
  abc@gmail.com                                      gmail
cde.nitish@yahoo.com                               yahoo
xyz.vijay@sarvang.com.com                          sarvang
```

Comment: @NitsPatel your welcome  but why you give back correct answer mark and donr mark may answer as useful ???

Comment: @NitsPatel and you mark one wrong  answer ??? that answer output is wrong

Comment: it was my mistake i edited my question after his answer but in comment section he describe how to get output so i marked as a correct answer

Comment: @NitsPatel Please set useful vote for my answer tnx

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original version of the question.

This may be simplest with a `case` expression to detect if there is a period before the `'@'`:

```
select (case when email like '%.%@%'
             then stuff(left(email, charindex('@', email) - 1), 1, charindex('.', email), '')
             else left(email, charindex('@', email) - 1)
        end)
from (values ('abc@gmail.com'), ('cde.nitish@yahoo.com'), ('xyz.vijay@sarvang.com.com')) v(email)
```

Comment: i am really sorry but my output will be slightly changed from previous i ask it should be 'gmail', 'yahoo', 'sarvang' means after '@' and before '.'

Comment: @NitsPatel . . . Invalidating answers to a question is rather rude.  You should have asked a new question.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution. I first get the position of the `'@'`, and then get the position of the `'.'` in the string prior to it (the `'@'`). Then I can use those results to get the appropriate substring:

```
SELECT V.YourString,
       SUBSTRING(V.YourString,D.I,A.I - D.I) AS StringPart
FROM (VALUES('abc@gmail.com'),
            ('cde.nitish@yahoo.com'),
            ('xyz.vijay@sarvang.com.com'))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX('@',V.YourString)))A(I) --Get position of @  to not repeat logic
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',LEFT(V.YourString,A.I))+1))D(I) --Get position of . to not repeat logic
```

Note for value of `'abc.def.steve@...` it would return `'def.steve'`; however, we don't have such an example so I don't know what the correct return value would be.

Comment: i got the result but i don't want to set my all string value because i have to update almost 1000 rows so its not possible i want with column name

Comment: I use `VALUES` as sample data @NitsPatel; obviously you would use your table not a `VALUES` operator. I don't have access to your table, so i use `VALUES` to create data i can test against.

Comment: No worries @NitsPatel . Please do mark my or Gordon's answer as the solution (which ever it is you use in the end) if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: i am really sorry but my output will be slightly changed from previous i ask it should be 'gmail', 'yahoo', 'sarvang' means after '@' and before '.'  my table name : tbl_data  and column name : Mail_ID please help me

Comment: If you've changed your question, edit it, @NitsPatel, but it sounds like you've completely changed the goal posts here; which really (in my opinion) means you should be asking a new question not invalidating all the answers you've received and expecting those that have tried to help you start all over again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this as a new answer, a the OP moved the goal posts from the original answer. My initial answer was based on their original question, not their "new" one, and it seems silly to remove an answer that was correct at the time:

```
SELECT V.YourString,
       SUBSTRING(V.YourString,A.I, D.I - A.I) AS StringPart
FROM (VALUES('abc@gmail.com'),
            ('cde.nitish@yahoo.com'),
            ('xyz.vijay@sarvang.com.com'))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX('@',V.YourString)+1))A(I)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',V.YourString,A.I)))D(I);
```

Comment: if want to get result using my column name instead of hard coded of string what should i changed

Comment: because i have to update record almost 1000 so its not possible to set all string value

Comment: My table name is tbl_data and string stored in Mail_id column name please help me in terms of table

Comment: I repeat my statement from before, @NitsPatel; I use `VALUES` for sample data; you would reply the "object" V with your own table.

Comment: ID Mail_ID                                 New_Value
1 nitish.p@gmail.com.com  NULL
2 nitish.p@gmail.com.com   NULL
3 nitish.p@gmaill.com.com NULL
4 nitish.p@outlook.com.com NULL    my table structure

Comment: Just replace `FROM (VALUES...) V(YouString)` with `FROM {Your Schema}.{YourTable} {Alias}` @NitsPatel (obviously use the correct names)